# i have a problem with my adaptive moving average trading system

Tags: c#, matrix

I created a trading system with an adaptive moving average on the average true range but the program reports this error to me

> the modifier public is not valid for this item

at line 21 of the code

```
public int avgTrueRange.value1 { get; set; }
```

I tried to change `public` but it always reports this error.

this is the code :

```
public class MediaMobileAdattiva : SignalObject
{
    public MediaMobileAdattiva(object _ctx): base(_ctx)
    {
        Range = 14;
        FirstLength = 10;
        AvgTrueRange.value1 = 1;
    }

    private IOrderMarket buy_order;
    public int Range { get; set; }

    public double FirstLength { get; set; }

    public int AvgTrueRange.value1 { get; set; }

    private double FirstAverage()
    {
        if (AverageTrueRange < AvgTrueRange.value1)
            return FirstLength;
    }

    protected override void Create()
    {
        // create variable objects, function objects, order objects
        buy_order = OrderCreator.MarketNextBar(new SOrderParameters(Contracts.Default, EOrderAction.Buy));
    }

    protected override void StartCalc()
    {
    // assign inputs 
    }

    protected override void CalcBar()
    {
        // strategy logic 
        if (Bars.CurrentBar > 1)
        {
            switch (FirstAverage)
            {
                case FirstLength:
                    return 1;
            }
        }

        if (Bars.CurrentBar > 1 && Bars.Close.CrossesOver(FirstAverage, ExecInfo.MaxBarsBack)
        {
            switch (FirstLength)
            {
                case 1:
                    buy_order.Send(Bars.Close[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a bunch of syntax and other errors here, you should start with a basic guide to C#.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to make a struct for AvgTrueRange:

```cs
public struct Range
{
    public int value1 {get; set;}
}
```

and change:

```cs
public int AvgTrueRange.value1 { get; set; }
```

to

```cs
public Range AvgTrueRange { get; set; }
```

Your code still won't compile btw but I don't really understand what you are trying to do in this line:

```cs
if (AverageTrueRange < AvgTrueRange.value1)
```

Also, change:

```cs
switch (FirstAverage)
{
    case FirstLength:
        return 1;
}
```

to

```cs
var avg = FirstAverage();
int? result = avg switch
{
    var avg when avg == FirstLength => 1,
    _ => null
};
if (result.HasValue) return result.Value;
```

as cases can only be constant values.